# Python csv writer wrong separator?

Tags: python, excel, csv, localization

Disclaimer: I'm in Europe.

According to [this page](http://www.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/2293-i-have-trouble-opening-csv-files-with-microsoft-excel-is-there-a-quick-way-to-fix-this) Excel uses the semicolon `;` as default separator in Europe to "prevent conflicts" with the decimal comma.

Now, I have this Python code:

```
import csv

data = [["test", "data"], ["foo", "bar"]]
writer = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "wb"), dialect="excel")
writer.writerows(data)
```

Which should generate this file:

```
test;data
foo;bar
```

but instead it uses commas. Why is this happening? `locale.getdefaultlocale()` returns `('nl_NL', 'cp1252')`.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. It's a relevant problem, it shows research effort, and the solution is not that obvious.

Comment: Various unrelated questions: Did you read the 4th solution in "this page" that you quoted? Who are the intended consumers of this SSV file -- people or computers? What will they do with it? Have you considered writing an XLS or XLSX file (which can be made locale-agnostic, with care)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because the csv.excel dialect is not locale aware.  If you wish to explicitly use semicolons as the delimiter then you need to either explicitly pass the delimiter to csv.open as

```
writer = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "wb"), delimiter=";")
```

or create a new dialect and register it

```
class excel_semicolon(csv.excel):
    delimiter = ';'
register_dialect("excel-semicolon", excel_semicolon)
```

In either case, you should test how floating point numbers are written ... I suspect they won't be written in the European format you desire (with a comma as the radix)

Answer (score 8):

The `excel` dialect is specified by the following attributes (in `Lib/csv.py`, [line 57](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/csv.py?view=markup)):

```
delimiter = ','
quotechar = '"'
doublequote = True
skipinitialspace = False
lineterminator = '\r\n'
quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
```

I see no hint, that this is somehow locale-dependent - hence you'll always get `,` with the default dialect.

But that's easily fixed, e.g.

```
class excel_semicolon(csv.excel):
    delimiter = ';'

writer = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "wb"), dialect=excel_semicolon)
```

Comment: Sure it's easily fixed, but I assumed if Python included the excel dialect it would implement it correctly =S

Comment: @miku: -1. After your second statement, `csv.excel.delimiter` refers to `';'` instead of `','`. Read the answer by @Donkopotamus.

Comment: @JohnMachin cannot reproduce in CPython 3.10