# How to read a CSV File delimited by '\x01' and create a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a requirement to read a CSV file which is `\x01` (^A) delimited and  create a dictionary for my lookup for processing my business logic further.
My input file contains many columns, i need to make 14 column as the key and rest as values.

Earlier the file was comma delimited and i was able to read the file and create the dictionary. know the file is coming to me as `\x01` delimited and my script is failing

this is how i created dictionary earlier

```
lake_dataset = csv.DictReader(open(local_registry_file_path+os.path.basename(registryPath),'rb'))
master_dir = {}
for row in lake_dataset:
    key = row.pop('TBL_DATASETLOCATION')
    key = key.lower().strip()
    master_dir[key] = row
```

Comment: here is my code to create the dictionary, i am getting array out of bound error IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                                                                                                     rawdata = open("/home/bgy/report/DATASET_2015-07-23.csv", "rb")
for row in rawdata:
 new_row = re.split('\^A', row)
 key = new_row[13]
 master_dir[key] = row

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the `delimiter='\x01'`in the DictReader:

```
lake_dataset = csv.DictReader(open(local_registry_file_path+os.path.basename(registryPath),'rb'), delimiter='\x01')
```

Comment: i am getting the following error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audit_report_test.py", line 37, in <module>
    for row in lake_dataset:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 108, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Comment: lake_dataset = csv.DictReader(open(local_registry_file_path +os.path.basename(registryPath),'rb'), delimiter='\x01')
master_dir = {}
for row in lake_dataset:
 key = row.pop('TBL_DATASETLOCATION')
 key = key.lower().strip()
 if("//") in (key):  
  key1 = key.replace("//","/")
  key = key1
 if key.endswith("/"):
  key0 = key
  key = key0[:-1] 
 master_dir[key] = row

Comment: ia m able to get rid off the error message but not able to pull the particular column and make it a key. not able to split the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom dialect that uses that character as a separator [as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423995/5113242).

```
import csv

class custom_sep(csv.excel):
    delimiter = chr(0x01)
csv.register_dialect("custom_sep", custom_sep)

data = """col1\x01col2\x01col3
foo\x01bar\x01baz
moo\x01mee\x01mah"""

data = csv.DictReader((x.strip() for x in data.split('\n')), dialect="custom_sep")
for row in data:
    print row
```

Comment: i did register but the problem is my file is not getting split, if you look at my code, i need to pull  out TBL_DATASETLOCATION column and make this a key and rest of the columns as values. i am not able to separate teh columns.

Comment: I added a fully working example. If your file doesn't work, it means the separator is not `\x01`.

Comment: Hey, i did the same thing and it worked, thanks for all your help

Comment: here is my code controlA = "\x01"
master_dir = {}
with open(local_registry_file_path +os.path.basename(registryPath),'rb') as lake_dataset:
 for line in lake_dataset:
  items = line.rstrip().split(controlA)  
  #key = line.pop('TBL_DATASETLOCATION')
  key = items[13]
  key = key.lower().strip()
  if("//") in (key):  
   key1 = key.replace("//","/")
   key = key1
  if key.endswith("/"):
   key0 = key
   key = key0[:-1] 
  master_dir[key] = line

Comment: Know i am able to split the file and create a dictionary, can you let me know how can i refer a nth column using the key.                                                       master_dir[src_path][48] this is how i am trying to get the refer the value at 49th column by passing the key but i am getting junk values.